# REF Error Caused by Currently Missing Data in PivotTable

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to grab numbers from a PivotTable and add it another cell. Currently, there is some data that is missing but will eventually become available as the year goes on and will populate in the PivotTable. I have the GETPIVOTDATA nested in a IF function. Everything seems to work fine until I add the false value.

I will not be the primary user of this workbook, so I want to minimize the work the main user would need to do to ensure the data is correct. I could update the formulas as the new data comes in, but I figure there must be a better way to handle this.

Any advice or alternative methods to complete this would be much appreciated.

Here is what I have currently:

```
=$J10+IF(ISREF(GETPIVOTDATA("id_no",$I$25,"column_group","keyword")), 0)
```

This is what I was trying that caused the error:

```
=$J10+IF(ISREF(GETPIVOTDATA("id_no",$I$25,"column_group","keyword")), 0, GETPIVOTDATA("id_no",$I$25,"column_group","keyword"))
```

Comment: Does "Currently, there is some data that is missing but will eventually become available as the year goes on..." mean that as the year goes on new rows/columns will be added to the pivot table? Is the formula referencing corresponding rows/columns? If so then perhaps as opposed to using ISREF, using ISBLANK(row/column header) would work.

Comment: Correct. New columns will be added to the pivot table throughout the year. Thanks for the suggestion. I will give it a try.